# opencv creates faulty pkg-config files

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, pkg-config

If I run the straight installation of opencv like this:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/some/path" ..
make install
```

opencv creates a faulty pkg-config file like this:

```
# Package Information for pkg-config

prefix=/some/path
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=
includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
includedir_new=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 2.4.10
Libs:  ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_contrib.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_core.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_features2d.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_flann.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_gpu.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_highgui.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_legacy.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ml.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ocl.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_photo.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_stitching.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_superres.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ts.a ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_video.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_videostab.so -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl
Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}
```

Which produces outputs, which can't be used directly for the compiler, or by cmake:

```
$ pkg-config opencv --libs
/sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_core.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_flann.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_ml.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_ocl.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_photo.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_superres.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_ts.a /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_video.so /sct/homes3/opencv/opencv_2_4_10/lib/libopencv_videostab.so -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

You can see that the libraries of opencv are given by their full path, and that no compiler flags are given.

A proper version of the `opencv.pc` should look like this:

```
# Package Information for pkg-config

prefix=/some/path
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}/lib
includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
includedir_new=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 2.4.10
Libs:  -L${libdir} -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl
Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}
```

So why is opencv/cmake producing such a pkg-config file?
Or am I doing something wrong with the `make install`?

Comment: Have you tried makepkg?

Comment: looks like it's a bug: http://code.opencv.org/issues/3485

Comment: @grapeot Wow this was reported 11 month ago and nothing happens. Whats wrong there?

Comment: personally I don't know... :( not a developer of opencv... guess the bug assignee just forgot about it... (and I was also puzzled by the problem, that's how I found this question...)